# How to establish connection between flutter and aws ec2?

Tags: flutter, amazon-ec2

I'm new to building mobile apps. I need to build a mobile app which uses flutter and AWS ec2 . How to establish connection between flutter and aws ec2? I really have no idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

lighter answer,

- allow default ports to your instance(Http=80,Https=443)
- SSH to EC2,
- Install Nginx (by default it listens on the above mentioned ports)
- Install a framework like Express for Node.JS
- Run your app in any port for example 5555(not 80 or 443 or anything below 1000) (express app on the context of this answer)
- now configure Nginx to route its traffic to port 5555 from 80
- after that all it comes down to doing REST request for the server

`http://<your-ec2-IP>/<express-app-route>`

I've given you a idea what should be done, looking at the procedures without knowing the steps would make this look like a very messy thing to do, google is your friend, google for every step

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. And I would like to know one more thing. Can I use socket programming using python to establish this connection?

Comment: the thing is at the core every connection is same, Http or Socket, of course you can

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definitely look into this.